# LINQ Filter a Table with one large array

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table for `cars` and a treeview so user can select a number of cars and see the detailed info

The problem is if user select many cars this line cause `StackOverflow` (not punt intended).

There are 1300 Cars. In this case `id[]` has 720 integers. With 163 id's works ok.

```
IEnumerable<car> cresult = db.cars.Where(c => id.Any(s => s == c.car_id)).ToList();
                                              ^^^
                                              int []
```

**What is the best way to filter my table with one large array?**

Error:

[image]

Comment: What type of LINQ is this? e.g. to SQL, to Entities (EF version?) etc.

Comment: @IvanStoev Is EF 6.0, with  Npgsql

Comment: Doesn't happen with SqlServer provider, should be something specific to Npgsql provider. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Contains` rather than `Any()` and doing your own compare.

```
IList<car> cresult = db.cars.Where(c => id.Contains(s => c.car_id)).ToList();
```

Also, it's probably not a good idea to cast to `IEnumerable<car>` once you've explicitly done the work to turn it into a list.

For further performance gains, you might consider using `HashSet<int>` rather than `int[]` - though admittedly, if this is being turned into a SQL query, it likely won't have much (if any) gain.

Comment: what you mean `doing your own compare` Do I need write a compare function?  and please can elaborate what isnt good idea do the cast?  Im just returning the list to show in the View .And I think `IEnumerable` is simpler than a `List` isnt?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Sorry, maybe the 'doing your own compare' was superfluous.. I was referring to the `s => s == c.car_id`. In regards to casting to `IEnumerable<int>`, it's typically recommended to be as *specific as possible* on return values. In this case, casting to `IEnumerable<int>` means you lose information such as `Count`, etc. You've already done the work turning it into a `List`, so you may as well expose the additional functionality. If you're simply passing it to a view control, this might not make a difference, but in general it's a good idea.

Comment: Work great, Shouldnt be much larger, But may I worry if `int[]` is more bigger?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I've found `Contains` works for up to around 10,000 items (although, that's on SQL Server). It would depend on how many parameters postgres supports. If/when you hit that limit, you'll need to batch the ids and do multiple queries and union the results in memory.

Comment: @Rob Isn't `Contains` translated to a  big `IN (...)` clause w/o parameters? +1 btw.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes it is, but not always. The last time I ran into it, it generated a parameter for each item, and then did `IN(@p0,@p1,@p2)`, etc. Admittedly though, the parameters were strings, which might explain why. Regardless, though, 10000 items also pushes the limits of the database engine as well - which might not *fail*, but would be extremely slow (another solution instead of batching is to bulk insert and do a join)